# New puppy devours food impossibly quick

Tags: dogs, health, eating, adoption

I rescued a puppy from a local rescue organization recently. The puppy is about 5-8 months old and is a German sheppard doberman mix. I feed him roughly 3 cups of dog food a day broken into 3 meals (breakfast, lunch, and dinner). Breakfast and lunch is a rounded scoop with dinner being a level scoop.

As soon as I put the food down my puppy devours it within <8 seconds. This seems absurdly fast to me but he also does not appear to get sick or have a problem holding it down. He seems to always be hungry but I'm told that is normal.

Is this normal for a puppy to eat so quickly?  Or is this a result of not being fed properly/normally until he was rescued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be normal, especially if the pup is used to having to compete with littermates for access to the food bowl. And dogs tend to eat quickly anyway, as recognized by the idiom "to wolf down a meal".

This may decrease over time as he realizes that nobody is trying to take the food away before he's done eating.